# call hidden value to highchart

Tags: javascript, asp.net, vb.net, highcharts

i have data from vb.net that i want to call to the y axis.

code behind:

```
 Dim yaxis As String
 If RadioButtonList1.SelectedItem.Value = 1 Then
     yaxis = "Fruit eaten"
 End If

 hidden10.Value = yaxis
```

javascript

```
 $(function () { 
    $('#container').highcharts({
        chart: {
            type: 'bar'
        },
        title: {
            text: 'Fruit Consumption'
        },
        xAxis: {
            categories: ['Apples', 'Bananas', 'Oranges']
        },
        yAxis: {
            title: {

               text: '** i want Fruit eaten here***'**

            }
        },
        series: [{
            name: 'Jane',
            data: [1, 0, 4]
        }, {
            name: 'John',
            data: [5, 7, 3]
        }]
    });
 });​


<asp:HiddenField ID="hidden10" runat="server" />
var a10 = $("#<%=hidden10.ClientID%>").val();
```

as you can see it says text: but i want hidden10 value to show...

my draw function which i already had

```
       function draw(d) {

           var testarray = JSON.parse(a);
           var testarray1 = JSON.parse(a1);
           var testarray2 = JSON.parse(a2);


           var yaxis = $("#<%=hidden10.ClientID%>").val();
```

testarray is data from the backcode.

behind code for the radiobuttons:

```
    Select Case RadioButtonList1.SelectedItem.Value
        Case 1

            Dim yaxis As String
            If RadioButtonList1.SelectedItem.Value = 1 Then
                yaxis = "fruit eaten"
            End If




            Dim serializer1 As New JavaScriptSerializer()

            Dim arrayJsonTest1 As String = serializer1.Serialize(testarray)
            Dim arrayJson11 As String = serializer1.Serialize(testarray1)
            Dim arrayJson12 As String = serializer1.Serialize(testarray2)

            hidden.Value = arrayJsonTest1
            hidden1.Value = arrayJson11
            hidden2.Value = arrayJson12

            ' Bind_kWhValues(Year1, Year2, Year3)
            ScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript(Me.Page, Me.GetType, "draw",         "javascript:draw(1);", True)



        Case 2
            Dim yaxis As String
            If RadioButtonList1.SelectedItem.Value = 2 Then
                yaxis = "fruits not eaten"
            End If

            hidden10.Value = yaxis


          ScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript(Me.Page, Me.GetType, "draw",         "javascript:draw(2);", True)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

yAxis: {
         title: {
                  text:Yaxis 
                 }
       },

Answer (score 1):

```
yAxis: {
         title: {
                  text:Yaxis 
                 }
       },
```

The above code works for me.
Make sure If RadioButtonList1.SelectedItem.Value = 1 Then this if condition is satisfied.
I tried following code:

```
var Yaxis = 'default';
function draw(d) {

       var testarray = JSON.parse(a);
       var testarray1 = JSON.parse(a1);
       var testarray2 = JSON.parse(a2);
        if(d == 1)
        {
            Yaxis='Fruit Eaten..';

        }

        else  if(d == 2)
        {
           Yaxis='Fruit not  Eaten..';
        }
        else 
        {
            Yaxis='Your Default value here...';
        }


       }
}
```

Comment: yeah that works, am trying to add 2 more hidden10 for value 1 and 2, (radiobuttons) but they still show it as Fruit Consumption even though i changed the name in the code behind....

Comment: Fruit Consumption is the title of your chart. You are setting YAxis in your code behind.

Comment: sorry i mean fruit eaten. basically that shows now, but because i have 3 charts its showing for all 3, but i just want it to show for the value 1. in the code behind i did the same thing and changed the name... i think its the draw function i need something on their.

Comment: I would prefer to do it on client side. On radio button change event make function in js and set hidden field value there and call your highchart function to render the chart. I had the similar scenario with dropdown selected index changed event. Also where you are setting the value of hiddenfield on what event?

Comment: You have to render whole chart again if you change single value in the chart then and then only it will show up with new data rendered in chart. Where you have your if condition? it will be helpful if you show your vb code as well.

Comment: i have shown my code behind, as you can see i have case 1 and 2, value 1 and 2, i need to put that in the function draw methods so it refreshes the data....

Comment: why you are not calling methods in your case 2? you are setting up the  yaxis value and not calling your draw function .

Comment: i have the script manager calling from the case2, but it shows the case1 name for somereason

Comment: I see you are passing static value to your draw function. now in your draw function use if else loop to set the variable Yaxis="fruit eaten" else Yaxis="fruits not eaten.." and remove it from code-behind. you dont need to set the value in the hidden field.

Comment: I updated my ans. Please try that and see if it works for you.

Comment: still giving me the same data, fruit eaten for both of them

Comment: OK now check what is your radiobutton selected value

Comment: Do you have autopostback="true" ?